# Adding a Custom Object to an ArrayAdapter. How to grab Data?

Tags: android, list, object, android-arrayadapter

This is what I have so far:

The Custom Object:

```
class ItemObject {
    List<String> name;
    List<String> total;
    List<String> rating;

public ItemObject(List<ItemObject> io) {
    this.total = total;
    this.name = name;
    this.rating = rating;
 }
}
```

The Call to the Adapter:

```
List<String> names, ratings, totals;

ItemObject[] io= new ItemObject[3];
io[0] = new ItemObject(names);
io[1] = new ItemObject(rating);
io[2] = new ItemObject(totals);

adapter = new ItemAdapter(Items.this, io);
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Assuming the above looks ok, my questions is how would I set up the ItemAdapter, it's constructor, and unwrap the three List's from the object.  And then, in the getView, assign these things:

each matching position to:

```
    TextView t1 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.itemName);
    TextView t2 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.itemTotal);
    RatingBar r1 = (RatingBar) rowView.findViewById(R.id.ratingBarSmall);
```

For example, position 0 in the array "names" to t1.
Position 0 in the array "totals" to t1.
Position 0 in the array "ratings" to r1.

EDIT:  I don't want someone to write the entire Adapter.  I just need to know how to unwrap the Lists from the Custom Object so I can use the data.  (*Something not even brought up or asked about in another question*)

Comment: This is awfully similar to your question yesterday: [Passing Multiple Lists<String> into ArrayAdapter](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11584398/1267661)

Comment: The other question was simply asking on how (or what method to use) to do something.  In fact, I am still researching HOW to do that.  This question is referring to one SPECIFIC way of doing that.  Also, a way NOT brought up at all in that question.  I am still deciding on how to handle this.   And I still thank everyone for their help in the answers that were provided.  I very well may go back to one of those ideas.

Comment: A common way of thanking people is to upvote the meaningful answers and to mark the best answer as correct.

Comment: I take a while but I always go back to it once I know what's what.  Although I should upvote sooner... (the answer isn't chosen, until I actually have one that I was able to use and implement)

Comment: Awesome. Luksprog has pointed you in the right direction, I'm not too sure anyone can significantly improve on it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your code will not work in its actual form. Do you really need lists of data in the `ItemObject`? My guess is no and you simply want a `ItemObject` that holds 3 Strings corresponding to the 3 views from your row layout. If this is the case:

```
class ItemObject {
    String name;
    String total;
    String rating;// are you sure this isn't a float

public ItemObject(String total, String name, String rating) {
    this.total = total;
    this.name = name;
    this.rating = rating;
 }
}
```

Then your lists will be merged into a list of `ItemObject`:

```
List<String> names, ratings, totals;
ItemObject[] io= new ItemObject[3];
// use a for loop
io[0] = new ItemObject(totals.get(0), names.get(0), ratings(0));
io[1] = new ItemObject(totals.get(1), names.get(1), ratings(1));
io[2] = new ItemObject(totals.get(2), names.get(2), ratings(2));
adapter = new ItemAdapter(Items.this, io);
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

And the adapter class:

```
public class ItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ItemObject> {

        public ItemAdapter(Context context,
                ItemObject[] objects) {
            super(context, 0, objects);         
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // do the normal stuff
            ItemObject obj = getItem(position);
            // set the text obtained from obj
                    String name = obj.name; //etc       
                    // ...

        }       

}
```

Comment: Since this was voted to be closed (for some reason) I am going to vote this as correct before its too late.  Wanted to make sure you get credit and this was what I was looking for!