# Get value from Activity to custom array adapter

Tags: java, android, android-adapter

I am creating chat application. So I wanted to add number of messages a user get from his friend. To show that I created custom `Array adapter` because my listview consists of friend name and `notification textview`.

[image: Friend List]

So, I have the data in my list_of_registerd_users activity:

[image: Data From Firebase]

How I can send this data to custom `array adapter` class to set the view of notification:

**Custom Array Adapter class**:

```
public class CustomArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private Context mContext;
    private int mRes;
    private ArrayList<String> data;

    private String numOfMsgs;

    public CustomArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource,
                              ArrayList<String> objects) {

        super(context, resource, objects);

        this.mContext = context;
        this.mRes = resource;
        this.data = objects;
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.getItem(position);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View row = convertView;
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        row = inflater.inflate(mRes, parent, false);

        String currentUser = getItem(position);

        TextView friendName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvFriendName);

        String Frndname = currentUser;
        friendName.setText(Frndname);


        TextView notificationView = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvNotif);


//here i wanted to get the data noOfMsgs
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "noOfMsgs:" + numOfMsgs, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            notificationView.setText(noOfMsgs);
        return row;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to update the list object which you are passing in CustomArrayAdapter and then notify the list.

adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

As you are passing the list object to adapter so any changes in list will automatically updated in object 'data'. You have to just update the view.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to initialize the adapter and attach the adapter to the ListView

```
ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<>();
items.add(item1);
items.add(item2);
items.add(item3);

CustomArrayAdapter<String> itemsAdapter = new CustomArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
listview.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);
```

Comment: i did that before in list_of_reg_user activity in oncreate() method i used custom format for getting the view that is R.layout.format_friends_list:
 listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listOfRegUsers);

        arrayAdapter = new CustomArrayAdapter(ListOfRegisterdUsersActivity.this,
                R.layout.format_friends_list, new ArrayList<String>());
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

Comment: @Leo but the string array you are passing to `CustomArrayAdapter` is empty, you have to add your items to it

Comment: check the list_of_registerd_users activity image second one i use arrayadapter.addAll(set) function. Here **set** have friends name from firebase database. I also wanted to send noOfMsgs from Activity to class CustomArray Adapter .

Comment: i get he solution from here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11584398/passing-multiple-listsstring-into-arrayadapter
no need to reply